# Remove multidimensional array with empty sub arrays using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array as follows. Every student has 7 arrays starting from Monday to Sunday and inner array of each has events for day

```
$array = [
    'Alex' => [
        [
            ['event' => 'eventName1'],['event' => 'eventName2']
        ],
        [
            ['event' => 'eventName3'],['event' => 'eventName4']
        ],
        [
            ['event' => 'eventName5'],['event' => 'eventName6']
        ],
        [
            ['event' => 'eventName7'],['event' => 'eventName8']
        ],
        [],
        [],
        []

    ], 
 'christoper'=>[
      [],[],[],[],[],[],[]
 ]
];
```

The output array should be

```
[
    'Alex' => [
        [
            ['event' => 'eventName1'],['event' => 'eventName2']
        ],
        [
            ['event' => 'eventName3'],['event' => 'eventName4']
        ],
        [
            ['event' => 'eventName5'],['event' => 'eventName6']
        ],
        [
            ['event' => 'eventName7'],['event' => 'eventName8']
        ],
        [],
        [],
        []

    ]
];
```

I have tried this

```
$array = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $array));
```

but the result is vain. Can anyone help me in getting desired output. I want to filter out students with no events

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<?php

$output = array_filter($array, function (array $studentDays) {
    foreach ($studentDays as $day) {
        // if there is a *non-empty* day, we return early and keep the whole record
        if (! empty($day)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // only empty days, so discard the record
    return false;
});
```

https://3v4l.org/AkshS

Answer (score 0):

Loop over array and apply `array_filter`

```
$array = [
    'Alex' => [
        [
            ['event' => 'eventName1'],['event' => 'eventName2']
        ],
        [
            ['event' => 'eventName3'],['event' => 'eventName4']
        ],
        [
            ['event' => 'eventName5'],['event' => 'eventName6']
        ],
        [
            ['event' => 'eventName7'],['event' => 'eventName8']
        ],
        [],
        [],
        []

    ], 
 'christoper'=>[
      [],[],[],[],[],[],[]
 ]
];

foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
    $array[$key] = array_filter($value);
}

print_r( $array );
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive call to [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) will do the job; in the outer call we check the size of the returned array to decide whether to keep that element or not (it will be 0 if the array consisted solely of empty arrays, as it does for 'christopher'):

```
$array = array_filter($array, function ($v) { return count(array_filter($v)); });
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/58dgs)